# Где находятся переменные column_id и column_name (Woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

В личном кабинете нужно добавить еще один заголовок, но все находится в переменной column_name и column_id, а изменить не могу, так как найти не могу их. В какой папке или где вообще они находятся?
В файле `orders.php` есть код

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_account_orders', $has_orders ); ?>
```

Comment: Откуда вы знаете названия переменных, если не можете их найти? Чувствую, вопрос совсем не о том.

Comment: Мне нужно отредактировать файл orders.php, и там есть эта переменная, но она там просто есть, а вот что в ней находится, я не вижу. А мне нужно изменить то, что в ней находится

Comment: Тебе нужно  не отредактировать файл, а ЧТО? https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy/710#710